# Swift Protocols and Extensions ~ when do methods get called

Tags: swift, protocols

Can someone help explain this protocol and extension from Ray Wenderlich's site:

```
    struct Pizza {
    let ingredients: [String]
}

protocol Pizzeria {
    func makePizza(ingredients: [String]) -> Pizza
    //func makeMargherita() -> Pizza
}

extension Pizzeria {
    func makeMargherita() -> Pizza {
        return makePizza(ingredients: ["tomato", "mozzarella"])
    }
}

struct Lombardis: Pizzeria {
    func makePizza(ingredients: [String]) -> Pizza {
        return Pizza(ingredients: ingredients)
    }
    func makeMargherita() -> Pizza {
        return makePizza(ingredients:["tomato", "basil", "mozzarella"])
    }
}

let lombardis1: Pizzeria = Lombardis()
let lombardis2: Lombardis = Lombardis()

print(lombardis1.makeMargherita())
print(lombardis2.makeMargherita())
```

Why does only lombardis2 make a pizza with basil? What I don't understand is why Lombardis1 uses the method described in the extension but l2 doesn't?

Thanks.

Comment: lombardis1 is of protocol Pizzeria so it will only call makeMargherita() from Pizzeria's extension, while lombardis2 is of type Lombardis that edits the makeMargherita() protocol function to add basil to the array.

Comment: Some of the code is missing. Do you have a link to the page you took this from?

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/110982/swift-interview-questions-answers

Comment: @NathanLevitt thanks, I assumed the protocol would be copied as part of the struct.

Comment: The very point of this example is to show you that when `makeMargherita` is included in protocol's requirements, i.e. explicitly declaring that objects that conform should implement this method, (that line you have commented out) it does dynamic dispatch of `makeMargherita`, whereas if it is commented out like it is above, the protocol is defined in such a way that it's saying `makeMargherita` is not part of the protocol that I expect conforming objects to implement, so I'll just call the protocol's default implementation when using a variable whose type is, in fact, the protocol.

Comment: I get how protocols work. What I don't understand in this case is L1 is built based on the Pizzeria protocol, which includes an extension func makeMarg...L2 is built on L1, so why doesn't it also conform to the protocol and get the extension?

Comment: First a terminology thing: The implementation of `makeMargherita` in the `Pizzeria` extension is called the protocol's "default implementation". And because `makeMargherita` is commented out in the protocol's definition, it is not part of the protocol's requirements (i.e. there is no expectation that conforming objects will implement this), so it will use static dispatch, not dynamic dispatch.

Comment: So, are you asking why `lombardis2` calls the `Lombardis` implementation? Because `Lombardis` overrode the protocol's default implementation and you've defined this variable as a `Lombardis` type. Or are you asking why `lombardis1` calls the `Pizzeria` implementation? Because it is defined as a `Pizzeria` object and since `makeMargherita` is not in protocol definition, it's statically dispatched, so it has no visibility to this override of the default implementation. It's a `Pizzeria` instance and so it's going to call the `Pizzeria` implementation.